# More Detailed Specification for RTMP

Tags: rtmp, specifications

I'm currently implementing an simple RTMP server using C++, and I have read the Adobe RTMP Specification.  I found the spec is not so well written, leaving so many implementation details unmentioned.

I also used WireShark and crtmpserver to check the packets sent/received by the client/server, and I found it's very difficult to determine what a server should respond upon a 'play' command from the client.

The Adobe's Spec only uses 4 TEXT pages to explain the 'play' command, and the server part description is absolutely NOT clear, because I monitored a lot of packets being sent when using WireShark and crtmpserver.

Thanks. Peter

Comment: Seriously, this is ridiculous, I'm working on a client that pushes RTMP and I have no idea what the server responses mean at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed the instruction written inside http://wiki.rtmpd.com/documentation

You can pull or push stream by editing the crtmpserver.lua

for example, to pull a stream, under externalStreams add the block

```
{
     uri="rtmp://<address of external server>",
     localStreamName="mytest",
     forceTcp=true,     --if true=TCP false=UDP
     keepAlive=true,    --if stream will continuously playback again when it ends
},
```

then to push a stream to another server, under targetServers, add the block

```
{
    targetUri="rtmp://<ip/folder of target server>",
    targetStreamType="live", -- (live, record or append)
    targetStreamName="mytest",
    localStreamName="local",
    keepAlive=true,
},
```

you can also get more info by subscribing at www.evostream.com